# How to update a column in all rows of a table?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have the code:

```
def show_dolar_today(self):

    rate = self.get_dolar_today()
    self.env.cr.execute('update product_rate set rate=%s where id=%s', (rate,1))
```

the record with `id = 1` is updated in the table, but I want to update all the records that are in the table, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `where` clause:

```
self.env.cr.execute('update product_rate set rate=%s', (rate,))
```

Comment: Did you miss a comma `(rate,)`?

Comment: @Sami the comma is intentional - without it, it's just `rate` in parenthesis. WIth it, it's a tuple that has a single element of `rate`.